# How to choose PFC controller and how to boost voltage

Tags: power-factor-correction

I have found [this](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/dm00801580-3048881.pdf) PFC controller (I am building a rectifier to ~500V). As I understand, because PFC uses a boost converter, it should be able to boost rectified voltage to bigger voltage. How would I set this voltage? Do PFC controllers have such ability? Or do they just make output ~325V (from 230V AC)?

Comment: Designers usually select a boosted voltage slightly above the maximum peak value of the input line. This is because the less you boost, the best the efficiency. Therefore, if your mains is 265 V rms as a max, it is not uncommon to find regulated voltages at 380 V dc for instance, 400 V being a maximum. Also, some designs include a boost follower mode where the regulated dc voltage changes with the input voltage, again to maximize efficiency: 250 V dc from 85 to 150 V rms and 380-400 V beyond. Some circuits do that automatically, some externally by altering the resistive division ratio.

Comment: On top of what @VerbalKint said, electrolytic capacitors peak at 400 V (price/performance), so going above 400 V DC for a 85-265 V AC input device becomes suboptimal.

Comment: Also - could PFC controllers deal with not perfect sinusoidal input? If it is in poor quality (amplitude top is chopped by other non-PFC rectifiers)?

Answer (score 1):

> *How would I set this voltage?*

Your device can modify the boosted value by adjusting the resistor ratio in red: -

[image]

The set voltage has to be larger than the peak AC voltage else you won't get a pseudo-resistive current being drawn from the AC line.

> *Do PFC controllers have such ability?*

I'm not saying that all PF controllers are like this (because that would be an exhaustive study). However, most that I have seen have this ability.